# Angular 2+ Зависимости для Lazy loading модулей

Tags: angular2

В ходе выяснения принципов работы Lazy loading модулей в Angular 2+ сложил некую картину. Хотелось бы получить обратную связь правильно ли я понял как это работает, если нет, то как это на самом деле работает?

Lazy loading модуль как отдельное приложение со своим скоупом зависимостей, собирается в отдельный чанк, и при поиске компонентов, сервисов, директив, или интерсепторов задекларированных в других модулях, нужно импортировать их через общий модуль типа `SharedModule`, в который сваливаются общие сущьности. Тоесть в случае с Lazy loading модулем, при поиске зависимостей angular не поднимается до `AppModule`. Lazy loading модуль сам и является вершиной графа зависимостей, а прямое добавление сущностей из других модулей в `providers`, ломает этот подход делая его частью общего дерева зависимостей, что заставляет его грузится в режиме обычного модуля сразу. Вероятно связи из `providers` подтягиваются на этапе сборки проекта. Выходом может быть только использование `imports` так как вероятно, эта конструкция срабатывает только в момент запроса к модулю. Этот вопрос наверно влючает в себя вопрос о жизненном цикле модуля, так как все говорят про жизненные циклы компонентов а модуль в таком разрезе обсуждать как-то не принято.

Итого:

1. Верно ли что зависимости `providers` и `imports` подтягиваются в разное время?
2. Какие основные этапы жизненного цикла принципиально влияют на то, в какой момент Lazy loading модуль будет загружаться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перехватчики не относятся к декларациям, так как это сервисы.

Нет никакого графа, боль-во людей вообще непонятно откуда берет эту информацию, НО `The biggest confusion regarding imported modules is that developers think they make a hierarchy.  All modules are merged during compilation phase.` У лейзи модулей есть свой инжектор, но если искомого провайдера там нет - то дальше лейзи модуль пойдет в рут инжектор, если же зависимости нет и в рут инжекторе, то будет эксепшн `NullInjectorError: No provider for %token%`.

Ответы на ваши вопросы:

1) Нет, не верно. В скомпилированном коде нет вообще такого понятия как `imports`, `providers`. На этапе компиляции `AOTCompiler` собирает информацию о модуле в `module.metadata.json`,  после этого рекурсивно обходит все модули объявленные в `imports`, "вытаскивает" провайдеры и мерджит все это дело в определенную структуру, которая называется `NgModuleDefinition`.

Например:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [HttpClientModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Скомпилированный код:

```
var AppNgModuleFactory = createModuleFactory(
    AppModule,
    [],
    function() {
        return moduleDef([
            moduleProviderDef(4608, HttpClient, HttpClient, []),
            moduleProviderDef(5120, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, (interceptor) => [interceptor], [])
        ]);
    }
);
```

`4608` это `4096 | 512 = 4608`, где `4096` - это `NodeFlags.LazyProvider`, а `512` - `NodeFlags.TypeClassProvider`, это битовая маска, которая описывает тип провайдера. А `5120` - это `4096 | 1024`, где `1024` - это `NodeFlags.TypeFactoryProvider`.

Второй аргумент - это токен, третий - это значение, которое инжектор получит по токену, четверый - это зависимости (если бы `HttpClient` инжектил что-то в свой конструктор).

Конечно там мерджатся все провайдеры из `HttpClientModule`, я просто не стал их все перечислять тут. Точно также и с другими модулями.

По поводу `SharedModule` и зачем он нужен. Все декларации (компоненты, пайпы и директивы) компилируются в "определения". Компоненты в `ViewDefinition`, пайпы и директивы в `NodeDef`. Благодаря дефинишенам можно потом создать фабрику. `exports` это синтаксический сахар, который просто в будущем дает возможность получить доступ к ссылкам на фабрики этих деклараций.

2) Ответ на этот вопрос вы найдете [здесь](https://medium.com/@overthesanity/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-v8-%D0%B8-angular-483aa7551de3)